# Conveying the turn "have yet to do something"

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

The turn "have yet to do something" can be used for saying that something has not happened or been done up to the present time, especially when you think it should have happened or been done.

- The Prime Minister has yet to make a formal statement.
- The company has yet to find a replacement for the director who left in October.
- Unless I'm mistaken, I've yet to receive your assignement / you have yet to submit your assignement.

I know that the turn can be conveyed by "ne pas avoir fait quelque chose" as

- Sans faute de ma part, je n'ai pas encore reçu votre devoir maison / vous n'avez pas encore soumis votre devoir maison.

What other ways exist to convey the same meaning?

Comment: Certaines [manipulations](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/have-yet-to) du tour peuvent aider à le comprendre davantage ou à mieux le traduire.

Comment: @némésie-t-île Merci. C'est nickel le site :-)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to convey this meaning, but nothing as precise and specific as "have yet to" in English.

Here are some variations to your proposition conveying the same meaning :

- "Sauf erreur de ma part, vous ne m'avez pas encore rendu votre devoir"
- "..., j'attends toujours/encore votre devoir"
- "..., vous devez toujours/encore m'envoyer votre devoir"